# asp.net datacontrol sum with Eval and other value

Tags: asp.net, repeater

Friends

In my Repeater control I want to sum these two value on Item Template,

```
<ItemTemplate>
<h4>
<%# Convert.ToDouble(Eval("price")) %>
  (sum +)
<%=hiddenMinprice.Value%>
 </h4>
</ItemTemplate>
```

can you please give me Idea about this?, I want to sum of Eval("price") and hidden Field value.I think it may simple and also we can use javascript but for practise please provide me tips and tricks for <%# and <%=   in asp.net Data controls.